# dblpy event isn't being called

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So my bot is on Top.gg, and I'm using dblpy to interact with the api. But for some reason the `on_dbl_vote` event is not being called, I can make commands to update the server count using `dblpy.post_guild_count()`, and get past votes using `get_bot_votes()`, so I really don't know what's wrong.

I've attached my code for the cog below, any help would be great :)

```py
import dbl as DBL
from discord.ext import commands

class dblcog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.dblpy = DBL.DBLClient(self.bot, TOKEN, webhook_path=WEBHOOK,
            webhook_auth=WEBHOOK_AUTH, webhook_port=PORT)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_dbl_vote(self, data):
        print("VOTE RECIEVED\n{data}")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(dblcog(bot))
```

Comment: Refer to [documenation](https://pypi.org/project/dblpy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other methods such as `dblpy.post_guild_count` work, it is most likely a configuration issue.

Make sure you are introducing the correct *URL* (`http://serverip:webhook_port/webhook_path`) to your webserver and its authorization key  on *top.gg*

It could also be a firewall problem, make sure your device does not have a firewall that could be blocking the requests on the webhook port. You might need to perform port forwarding.

You should have a look at their [**documentation**](https://dblpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) and contact them for any further inquiries, as this does not look to be related to programming.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful. I'd formatted the webhook the wrong way around